# ERROR: TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=("'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType",)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I typed up a listener for pyTelegramBotApi and it works until I throw something that's not a command at it and it runs this error 2019-08-13 22:35:40,074 (util.py:65 PollingThread)

`ERROR - TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=("'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType",)`

```
    for m in messages:
        if m.content_type == 'text':
            # print the sent message to the console
            print(str(m.chat.first_name) + " [" + str(m.chat.id) + "]: " + m.text)
```

Expected output, Message shows up in console
Result: Error

Answer (score 1):

This is a while old but just ran into the same error and figured out, that the cause were the message handlers I provided before. I hadn't provided the (single) commands to handle in a list. So instead of typing (correct way):

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
```

I used (incorrect way):

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands='help')
```

Although this works for known (i.e provided) commands, this caused me the same error for unknown commands and plain text messages. Hope it helps (don't know, since you don't provide more info in your code).